# 'DNN' object has no attribute 'fit_generator' in ImageDataGenerator() - keras - python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Following code is developed for identify 5 image classes using keras and python with tensorflow backend. I have used imageDataGenerator but when I run this, it's started to train and after a while, following error occured.

How can I solve this?

> Training Step: 127  | total loss: 0.01171 |
>   time: 32.772s | Adam | epoch: 005 | loss: 0.01171 - acc: 0.9971 --
>   iter: 1536/1550 Training Step: 128  | total loss: 0.01055 | time:
>   36.283s | Adam | epoch: 005 | loss: 0.01055 - acc: 0.9974 | val_loss: 3.05709 - val_acc: 0.6500 -- iter: 1550/1550
>   -- Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes. Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes. Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/My Projects/FinalProject_Vr_01.2/CNN_IMGDG_stackoverflow.py', wdir='D:/My
>   Projects/FinalProject_Vr_01.2')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 704, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/My
>   Projects/FinalProject_Vr_01.2/CNN_IMGDG_stackoverflow.py", line 191,
>   in 
>       model.fit_generator(train_generator,
>
> AttributeError: 'DNN' object has no attribute 'fit_generator'

```
import cv2                
import numpy as np         
import os                
from random import shuffle 
from tqdm import tqdm      
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential

TRAIN_DIR = 'train'
VALID_DIR = 'validate'
TEST_DIR = 'test'
IMG_SIZE = 128
LR = 1e-3
train_samples = 1500
valdate_samples = 250
epochs = 5
batch_size = 10



MODEL_NAME = 'snakes-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')

def label_img(img):
    print("\nImage = ",img)
    print("\n",img.split('.')[-2])
    temp_name= img.split('.')[-2]
    print("\n",temp_name[:1])
    temp_name=temp_name[:1]
    word_label = temp_name


    if word_label == 'A': return [0,0,0,0,1]    
    elif word_label == 'B': return [0,0,0,1,0]
    elif word_label == 'C': return [0,0,1,0,0]
    elif word_label == 'D': return [0,1,0,0,0]
    elif word_label == 'E' : return [1,0,0,0,0]   

def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data


def create_validate_data():
    validating_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(VALID_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(VALID_DIR,img)
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        validating_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])
    shuffle(validating_data)
    np.save('validate_data.npy', validating_data)
    return validating_data


def process_test_data():
    testing_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
        path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR,img)
        img_num = img.split('.')[0]
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
        img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])
    shuffle(testing_data)
    np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
    return testing_data

train_data = create_train_data()
validate_data = create_validate_data()


import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression




import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()


convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 5, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')



if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
    model.load(MODEL_NAME)
    print('model loaded!')


train = train_data[:]
validate = validate_data[:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]


validate_x = np.array([i[0] for i in validate]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
validate_y = [i[1] for i in validate]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=epochs, validation_set=({'input': validate_x}, {'targets': validate_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',
                                                    target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('validate',
                                                        target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='categorical')


model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=25,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=25)


model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defining your Neural Network you can use do it using the Keras. (What you have done here is defining the network using Tensorflow. It's not having fit_generator method.)

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
```

These are the layers that you can use with Keras for your application. Then initialize your DNN with `DNN = Sequential()`

Refer this [simple classifier](https://github.com/haritha91/Cats-Dogs-Classifier---Keras) written with Keras and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your model object is an instance of the `tflearn.DNN` class, which simply does not have a `fit_generator` method. This method is only available for keras objects. Maybe you could define your architecture in keras and you would be able to use your data generators.

Comment: can you please explain on which convnet object, fit_generator should called and how to?

Comment: @LakwinC any Keras model (Sequential or Model classes).

Answer (score 0):

Other Opinion

If you want to see a Model and the ACC, lose

You need to use tensorboard

Example 1 : In Colab

```
load_ext tensorboard
tensorboard --logdir='/tmp/tflearn_logs'
```